# Slow concurrent postgres inserts into separate tables with indexes

Tags: postgresql, sqlperformance, citus

I'm running into an issue where I have 24 insert queries which all insert into different tables (shards), and they run slowly when the inserts are performed concurrently. When I run them sequentially, they're pretty fast. Strange thing, these all insert into other physical tables, so I don't understand where this severe contention would come from. I'm using citus, so I'd really like to see a performance gain inserting in parallel into different shards. But I'm 99% sure the problem is not citus-specific.

All 24 queries have the following form:

```
INSERT INTO schema.rtsepezocoav_p_452_119046 AS citus_table_alias (se_id, pe_id, zo_id, co_id, value_num, ad_id) SELECT ...
INSERT INTO schema.rtsepezocoav_p_452_119040 AS citus_table_alias (se_id, pe_id, zo_id, co_id, value_num, ad_id) SELECT ...
```

rtsepezocoav_p_452 is a partition of the parent table rtsepezocoav (declarative partitioning)

They all insert around 100k new records into a table (shard) which contains around 2Mio records.

All tables have 3 btree indexes on them. I understand inserting into tables with indexes slows things down, but what I don't understand is the severe degradation in performance when performing these inserts concurrently...

When I run them sequentially, they all take less than 2s:

```
Timing is on.
INSERT 0 94052
Time: 1860.400 ms (00:01.860)
Timing is on.
INSERT 0 95136
Time: 1798.271 ms (00:01.798)
...
```

When I fire off the 24 queries in parallel (through psql command ended with '&' in the terminal), they take much longer: around 13s.

```
INSERT 0 94052
Time: 12234.630 ms (00:12.235)
INSERT 0 95136
Time: 13207.503 ms (00:13.208)
INSERT 0 96049
Time: 13481.625 ms (00:13.482)
INSERT 0 93804
Time: 13684.117 ms (00:13.684)
INSERT 0 97342
Time: 14657.759 ms (00:14.658)
```

When instead of inserting, I just count(1) in parallel, I don't see any concurrency issues, so the problem is in writing.

I'm on postgres12, on a machine with 250GB ram and 12 cores.

I've tried playing with my postgres settings, to no avail however. Some of the settings which are probably most relevant:

```
shared_buffers  64000MB
temp_buffers    80MB
work_mem    100MB
maintenance_work_mem    2GB
wal_buffers 16MB
effective_cache_size    192000MB
min_wal_size    1GB
max_wal_size    4GB
synchronous_commit  off
```

The last tweak seems to improve performance when I run standard pgbench tests. But for my actual queries, I don't see any difference.

Is there some setting I'm missing ? I'm really hoping Postgres can handle synchronous inserts smoothly when they don't touch the same table where the inserts end up...

Comment: So doing 24 times more work takes 6 times longer.  Why would you not expect that?   You have plausibly decided that writing is the bottleneck, but have not described your IO system.

Comment: It's a rotational disk (not a SSD). In a perfect world I'd expect a performance improvement corresponding with the # of cores I have (x12). Of course, that's just theoretical, and seemingly disk IO is the bottleneck. But still, to go from a total running time of 24x2=48s to 12s for parallel inserts only corresponds to a 4x increase. Quite a bit lower than the theoretical improvement. Maybe I have unrealistic targets in my head, but I would expect an improvement closer to 12x, because the inserts are not that big + they happen in other tables so I don't see the contention issue.

Comment: Unless every table (and its associated indexes) is on a different disk, that expectation is not very realistic.